# sync failed after adding firebase to project

Tags: android, firebase

**I am getting this error**

> 6:11 PM   Gradle sync failed: Failed to notify dependency resolution
>   listener.
>                 The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.4,11.0.4],
>   [15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check
>   your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}


allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.neoline.whrilloprovider"
        minSdkVersion 17
          targetSdkVersion 26
        vectorDrawables.generatedDensities = ['hdpi', 'xxhdpi']
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters '— no-version-vectors'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }


    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not include `com.google.android.gms:play-services:X.X.X`.  Doing so pulls in ALL of the Google Play services APIs, making your APK larger than needed and increasing build time.  Instead, include only the APIs you need, as described in the [Setup Instructions](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

You must also use compatible versions of the Firebase and Play Services libraries.  If you want to use `firebase-core:16.0.0`, use the latest version of the Play Services APIs.  They are listed in Table 1 of the Setup Instructions linked above.  Most are 15.0.1; a few are 15.0.2.  If other dependencies or code force you to use `play-services-xxx:11.0.4`, then use `firebase-core:11.0.4`.  Note that those versions are [nearly a year old](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after adding google tag manager v.11.0.4 as described in the [GTM documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/) into my project. Before that, I had added firebase analytics v.16.0.1 into my project. Version 11.0.4. of GTM is old. You can look in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/) for current version.

Upgrading google tag manager to 16.0.1 solved the issue in my case.